# Setting the text in jTextField and then retrieving that text

Tags: java, swing, jframe, textfield, gettext

```
package test2;
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

private static void valueGen(javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1) {

    String x = jTextField1.getText();
    System.out.println(x);
}
public NewJFrame() {
    initComponents();
}

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){                                         
    jTextField1.setText("Hello");

}                                        

private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            

}                                           

public javax.swing.JTextField getTextField() {
    jTextField1.getText();
    return this.jTextField1;
}

public static void main(String args[]) {

     NewJFrame myFrame = new NewJFrame();
     valueGen(myFrame.getTextField());

     java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
        }
    });

}

private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;

}
```

I have a program as shown above.  I need to set the text "hello" in a text field when the submit button is clicked. It works. But then i need to use that text in a function called valueGen where it is printed. But the text doesn't get printed by executing the above code. What is wrong with this code?

Comment: `jTextField1.getText();` doesn't do anything useful.... And did you mean `myFrame().setVisible(true);` instead of `new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);`. Also, the code you've provided is a mess and doesn't compile.

Comment: what can i give instead of jTextField1.getText(); to fetch the value from that textfield?

Answer (score 0):

1. It's unorganized. Always put class variables at the top.
2. Like Cool Guy said, put `myFrame` instead of `new NewJTest()`
3. valueGen is actually being called **before** you can click the button. Put it in the `jTextField1ActionPerformed`; that might fix it.

Comment: It's unorganized because this is the way it's generated in netbeans. I tried what u said but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

In netbeans out put of the ***System.out.println();*** will be displayed in the output window as shown in the bellow picture.
If you want to display it as a message replace the following method with your ***valueGen()*** method.

```
private static void valueGen(javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1) {

String x = jTextField1.getText();
System.out.println(x);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, x);
}
```

And use ***myFrame.setVisible(true);*** to make visible your JFrame.

```
public void run() {

            NewJFrame myFrame = new NewJFrame();
            myFrame.setVisible(true);
 valueGen(myFrame.getTextField());
        }
```

[image: Out put of System.out.println()]